# how to replace WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data ); with boost:asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, winsock, wsastartup

I have native dll project which I use from C# via CLI wrapper. In `Initialize` method of dll i'm calling

```
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
```

This works fine.
Now I"ve decided to move entire dll to boost::asio (because I will port it to Linux and I want to enable /Za compiler option).

The question is - where and how should I replace `WSAStartup` call?

- move it to CLI wrapper or to the top-level C# project?
- replace it with some boost::asio call (which method to call?)

Answer (score 2):

`Boost.Asio` initialises `Winsock` before `main()` - it uses a static object for this purpose. Here is an excerpt from `winsock_init.hpp`:

```
// Static variable to ensure that winsock is initialised before main, and
// therefore before any other threads can get started.
static const winsock_init<>& winsock_init_instance = winsock_init<>(false);
```

So, in your case `Winsock` will get initialised on dll load.

(That's said, I'm afraid you can't compile `Asio` under Windows with `/Za`, but you also don't have to do this in order to make your code portable to Linux.)

Comment: i don't need to compile Asio (i did that already :), only use it in my project